# Uso dei trattini e delle lineette in Italiano

Tags: punctuation

Nella lingua inglese scritta, specialmente in alcune guide di stile nate dopo l'avvento della videoscrittura, si pone l'enfasi su entità diverse dettagliate in [questa domanda](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen).

Il sito della Crusca divide l'uso solamente in [trattino lungo e trattino corto](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/punteggiatura).

Esistono regole di stile consolidate per l'uso dei diversi segni di punteggiatura disponibili nei comuni *font* tipografici, per quanto concerne l'uso della lingua italiana ed in particolare per la stesura di manuali tecnici?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compendiando quello che prevedono la grammatica di Serianni, il *Manuale di stile* di Lesina e la pagina della Crusca che citi, in italiano si usano effettivamente (per lo più) due lunghezze: il trattino breve e quello lungo. (Qualcuno li chiama rispettivamente trattino e lineetta, mentre altri usano il termine “trattino” o “lineetta” per entrambi, e quindi è meglio specificare).

Il trattino breve si usa (in genere senza spazi prima né dopo):

- per andare a capo;
- per collegare “due membri di un composto che non presenti una stabile univerbazione” (“socio-linguistica”, “mini-bus”, se non si preferisce scriverli uniti) e in termini formati giustapponendo due sostantivi (“guerra-lampo”);
- per gli intervalli numerici (“alle pagine 120-135”);
- per separare due nomi propri o comuni che formano un qualche nesso (“il derby Milan-Inter”, “gli incontri governo-sindacati”), o analogamente due aggettivi (“gli aspetti linguistico-filologici”);
- con alcuni prefissi e prefissoidi, specie in formazioni occasionali (“i movimenti anti-apartheid”).

Il trattino lungo si usa (in genere preceduto e seguito da uno spazio):

- per introdurre il discorso diretto (in alternativa ai due punti e le virgolette);
- per racchiudere un inciso (“Malgrado ciò – o forse grazie a questo fatto – aveva ottenuto un notevole successo”).

Raramente si usa anche un tratto ancor più lungo per usi tipografici speciali (a volte per contrassegnare le singole voci di un elenco, o per indicare parti mancanti di un testo lacunoso, e in questo caso la lunghezza del tratto può essere proporzionale a quella della parte mancante).

Comment: Il trattino lungo è quello che in inglese si chiama _en dash_ (cioè trattino largo come il carattere _n_), codice Unicode [U+2013](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (decimale: 8211). Altri trattini si trovano [qui](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm)

Comment: Aggiungerei che il trattino breve si usa anche nel linguaggio scientifico, specie in quello chimico e biologico; quando si susseguano due parole composte che abbiano in comune il secondo elemento, la parola iniziale per esigenze di brevità può ridursi al primo elemento seguito dal trattino: "nel caso di *epato*-  e *nefropatie* gravi" (= di epato*patie* e di nefro*patie*).