# Differenze tra l'uso delle lineette [dash] in inglese ed in italiano

Tags: english-comparison, punctuation, writing

Esistono differenze nel'uso? Mi riferisco esclusivamente all' *em dash* , ovvero il trattino lungo utilizzato per separare parti della frase —e non singole parole. Faccio alcuni esempi dell'uso inglese:

> "He is the friend —the only one— that helped me in that situation."
>
> "Tim —my little nephew— is very shy"

Approfondendo lo studio dell'inglese, ho preso l'abitudine di usare questo tipo di punteggiatura anche in italiano. Ma non sono sicura sia corretto: possibili differenze possono riguardare sia l'aspetto grafico che l'uso.

[Per esempio in inglese consigliano di evitarlo in testi molto formali. In italiano mi sembra di trovare più spesso le virgole o le parentesi, che vengono usate in modo simile.]

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE, @Cindie!

Comment: grazie @Charo ! :) Sono felice di aver trovato questo utilissimo sito

Comment: Hai visto [questa domanda](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/uso-dei-trattini-e-delle-lineette-in-italiano), un po' più generale della tua?

Comment: Si l'ho vista poco fa. Risponde però solo in parte alla mia domanda, descrivendo gli usi in italiano. Mi interessava in particolare l'eventuale differenza con l'inglese (da cui ha origine), in modo da evitare errori... e solo per questo tipo di trattino (mentre quello corto ha bene o male lo stesso uso in entrambe le lingue).

Comment: Perché dici che ha origine dall'inglese?

Comment: Ho preso [una pagina a caso](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fp0ho09qz817850/IMG_4959.JPG?dl=0) di un libro vecchio a caso (Alfredo Panzini, *Il mondo è rotondo*, Mondadori 1932), di un periodo in cui l'inglese in Italia non era certo diffuso né amato, e ci sono le lineette sia per i dialoghi che per gli incisi di cui parliamo qui.

Comment: Così mi aveva detto la mia professoressa, allora l'ho preso per buono... non ci avevo riflettuto molto ed in effetti non ne sono affatto sicura. Dovrei approfondire. Ne sai qualcosa?

Comment: Hmm interessante. Non mi occupo di linguistica quindi è la prima volta che leggo di questo argomento. Ho trovato solo questo passaggio [commento successivo] in un articolo sul sito della BBC. Sembra che non sia chiaro da dove siano spuntate esattamente le lineette.. in ogni caso hanno origini parecchio antiche! Non pensavo.

Comment: '' [...]a 12th Century Italian writer named Boncompagno da Signa proposed an entirely new system of punctuation comprising only two marks: a slash (/) represented a pause while a dash (—) terminated sentences. The fate of da Signa’s dash is murky – it may or may not be the ancestor of the parenthetical dash, like those that surround these words – but the slash, or virgula suspensiva, was an unequivocal success.''

Comment: Fonte: http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20150902-the-mysterious-origins-of-punctuation

Comment: Forse [questo articolo](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html) potrebbe essere utile per comparare gli usi in lingua inglese to quelli in italiano.

Answer (score 1):

L'uso del trattino lungo in italiano è stato introdotto dalle traduzioni di libri dall'inglese.
Ha generalmente lo scopo di inserire un'interruzione nel testo, per introdurre un discorso diretto.

Rif. [Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/trattino_%28Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano%29/)

Comment: Intendevi “discorso **diretto**”?

Comment: Si, grazie della correzione.

Answer (score -1):

Io uso ordinariamente il “—” e, ormai, vedo che è comunemente usato nei libri e sulla stampa.

Questi due esempi mostrano come il “—” talvolta (a) può essere direttamente usato al posto della virgola, aumentando la leggibilità del periodo, ma talvolta (b) no.

(a) La società moderna — pur consapevole che l'era del petrolio è prossima alla fine — non investe adeguatamente nelle energie realmente alternative.

(b) Cotanto alte asserzioni — nella specie, “che minchiata” — dovrebbero essere motivate, sennò è come non esistessero.

Infine, non vedo nessuna ragione per evitarne l'uso in 'testi formali', anzi, io l'ho trovato spesso lì.

Comment: Elberich, ti invito a sostituire il tuo primo esempio con un altro.

Comment: Sono totalmente d'accordo con @DaG, Elberich: cerca di evitare questo tipo di opinioni personali, per favore. Questo non è il sito adatto per esprimerle.

Comment: @charo, ho sostituito l'esempio, ma credo queste siano incomprensibili ed illiberali forme di censura.

Comment: Ti sembra davvero meglio, Elberich? Non c'entra la censura: è solo che qui si parla di italiano, non di geopolitica.

Comment: Per carità, Elberich, scegli un esempio più neutro.

Comment: La nuova frase non sembra davvero diversa dalla vecchia.

Comment: @charo, ho editato ancora l'esempio, ma ciò è davvero esagerato se non persecutorio.

Comment: I casi sono due: o citi frasi di qualcuno (e le attribuisci), oppure le inventi. Non vedo motivi perché le *tue* opinioni debbano essere adoperate come esempi. Per essere franco, un motivo lo vedo: usare questo sito per esprimerle. Continuando nella franchezza, trovo che spesso adoperi linguaggio scurrile quendo non è affatto necessario; credo che ci siano migliaia di esempi adatti in cui non ci si riferisce, nemmeno in modo figurato, a parti del corpo. Intento persecutorio? Ma fammi il piacere!

Comment: No, respingo tutte le accuse, @egreg.

Comment: Non ho portato nessuna accusa. Ho solo espresso ciò che penso, basandomi sulla lettura dei tuoi messaggi e sui commenti precedenti, in cui non vedo alcun intento persecutorio.